# I have added dropdownlist at first row of gridview.Now i want to bind this dropdownlist with some static column

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, c#-3.0

Dropdownlist at first row is empty.i need to add column inside dropdown.here is my code:

```
  private void grdbind()
   {
    DataTable db = new DataTable();
    db = (DataTable)Session["csvdata"];
    DataRow newrow = db.NewRow();
    db.Rows.InsertAt(newrow, 0);
    dgData.DataSource = db;
    dgData.DataBind();


}
```

And this code is use to add dropdown at first position:

```
 protected void dgData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl;
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "ddlCol" + i.ToString();

                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);
            }
        }


    }
```

Now what i want is to bind this dropdown.??

Comment: Why don't just set the `DataSource` and `DataBind()` the `ddl`?

Comment: @mshsayem inside rowdatabound????

Comment: yep. The code will execute only once

Comment: actually i have to add 10-15 columns like firstname,lastname in dropdown..please  let me know how to do it..i think i have to create datatable and then i have to add all columns in datatable and then bind to dropdown??

Comment: How can a dropdownlist hold columns?

Comment: why can't be add datacolumn to dropdown???